# Navigation Drop Down Menu MouseOut Delay

Tags: jquery

How would I add a delay to stop the drop down menu from closing when the visitors mouse leaves the menu? Some of these menus go deep so I would hate for the menu to close on someone accidentally.

```
    <div class="menu">
  <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/products/">Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
                    <a href="product1">product type</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="lin1">product1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a href="link">product type 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="link">product2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href="klink">Where To Buy</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="link">place1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="link">Contact Us</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [this JS library](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) built for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mouseout event and the setTimeout method.

See [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yg3dyq7b/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#menu').on('mouseout',function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert("I'm one second late");
        },1000);
    });

});
```

When you hover the `#menu` nothing happens but when your cursor leaves the menu it will trigger an action (in this case an alert) after 1 second (or 1000 milliseconds).

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I am a newbie when it comes to jQuery, what would I replace the alert function with to keep the menu open?   :(

Comment: Please describe exactly what you want ... I'm not sure I'm understanding the requirements. Make a JsFiddle with an example ...

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to get back to you, but [I have made a JSFiddle with the HTML/CSS for the drop down menu](http://jsfiddle.net/thecreativepage/2pkqyp11/). When users are trying to use the drop down menu and their cursor leaves the LI the whole drop down closes. I would like to leave it open for a second or so, so in case the users mouse leaves it accidentally. The drop downs will have a lot of pages so I can see this being an issue. Thank you so much!